# Use JSON environment variable for Play Framework application.conf

Tags: java, json, playframework, environment-variables

I have created an environment variable which key is MYCUSTOMCONFIG and its value is a JSON which looks like:

```
{
   "test": {
     "first": "sometext"
   }
}
```

I would like to have first's value from application.conf. I already know that how should I reference to an environment variable `${?key}`.
 How should I do that with JSON in Play Framework 2.4.4? Is it possible or there is another way to reference to JSON environment variables.
It is a Java app.

Comment: Isnt it about just getting that property with `System.getProperties` and parsing JSON?

Comment: nope, want to get it from application.conf. I should use ${?MYCUSTOMCONFIG} and something more but I don't know the proper way

Comment: Ahh right, didnt noticed that